# How to transfer asp.net grid view data in HTML table

Tags: asp.net, html, email, gridview

I am working in asp.net and in that i am using grid view and now i want to convert grid view data which is dynamic to the html table so i can send an email. if any one know it please tell me.
Thank You

Answer (score 6):

You can use

```
   using System.IO;
   using System.Text;
   using System.Net.Mail;

private string GridViewToHtml(GridView gv)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(sb);
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
    gv.RenderControl(hw);
    return sb.ToString();
}

protected void SendMailButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.Body = GridViewToHtml(GridView1);
    mail.IsBodyHtml = true;
    // The same logic as you use for sending mail
}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{

}
```

Comment: my problem is npt sending email, my problem is that how to convert asp.net grid view data in to tables

Comment: @Renu123c why you need tables?

Comment: @Renu123 - You will get gridview html in `sb.ToString();`. I think this is the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Kettic GridView control can easily [export the data in GridView to HTML](http://www.kettic.com/winforms_ui/csharp_guide/gridview_data_export_html.shtml) and create an html format file to viewing in a web browser or MS Word.