# How to Email HTML Content using C#

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, email, gmail

I have a HTML page (using div tags) How to put body as html tags?
same as [image] i just want to mail same format Receipt

code

```
using System.IO;  
using System.Net;  
using System.Net.Mail;  


string to = " "; //To address    
string from = ""; //From address    
MailMessage message = new MailMessage(from, to);  

string mailbody = "In this article you will learn how to send a email using Asp.Net & C#";  
message.Subject = "Sending Email Using Asp.Net & C#";  
message.Body = mailbody;  
message.BodyEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;  
message.IsBodyHtml = true;  
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587); //Gmail smtp    
System.Net.NetworkCredential basicCredential1 = new  
System.Net.NetworkCredential("yourmail id", "Password");  
client.EnableSsl = true;  
client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;  
client.Credentials = basicCredential1;  
try   
{  
    client.Send(message);  
}   

catch (Exception ex)   
{  
    throw ex;  
}
```

Comment: Not really sure what's being asked here.

Comment: @john How to use html tags in email body ??

Comment: What's wrong with this?: `message.Body = mailbody;`?

Comment: @aparnarai create PDF file using crystal report and attached it to e-mail. It is more clean way to do it rather than attaching html file.

Answer (score 0):

`message.IsBodyHtml = true;` is already set to `true`, so you have just to replace your mailbody by a html formatted text, something like this :

```
string mailbody = "<html><body>In this article you will learn how to send a email using Asp.Net & C#</body></html>";
```

Comment: i am using GridView in html , how to replace it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3210240/how-to-transfer-asp-net-grid-view-data-in-html-table